# Having a hard time resizing a JTable

Tags: java, swing

I've having a really hard time resizing my JTable, I attempted to make the left-column a set width, while having the right column fill out the rest of the table, and the left columns width will change, but it extends it's container (And therefor cuts off some of the data) Image below:

http://gyazo.com/6e928b55f699622470e05fe06f2d9a23 (Image type not supported??)

As you can see the "Us" is cut off of the word `User`.

Here's what I've tried to resize this, all of which have had absolutely zero effect.

```
setBounds(any, any, any, any) -- No effect
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(any, any)); --- No effect
```

Then I tried some cheap-hacks in the Panel that it's a child of:

```
childPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
int index = Utils.getComponentIndex((childPanel.add(friendsList)));
childPanel.getComponent(index).setBounds(any, any, any, any);
```

which also had no effect.

The one that's bothering me most is that setBounds() isn't working, becasue that's what I'm using for everything (null layout, first jframe application, and I like being able to use pixel-locations for everything).

Here's the code: (**Extends JPanel**)

```
public SocialPanel() {
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setBounds(650, 0, 150, 400);
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));


    friendsList = new FriendsList();
    ignoreList = new IgnoreList();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Social Pane");
    title.setBounds(45, 3, 75, 25);

    childPanel = new JPanel();
    childPanel.setBounds(0, 30, 150, 325);
    childPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
    childPanel.add(friendsList);

    JButton showFriends = new JButton("F");
    showFriends.setBounds(15, 360, 50, 30);

    JButton showIgnore = new JButton("I");
    showIgnore.setBounds(80, 360, 50, 30);


    this.add(title);    
    this.add(childPanel);
    this.add(showFriends);
    this.add(showIgnore);
}
```

Then ofcourse, the friendslist.java (**Extends JTable**)

```
public FriendsList() {
    this.setGridColor(Color.gray);
    this.setShowGrid(true);
    this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new SocialCellRenderer());
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1, 1));
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel)getModel();
    dtm.addColumn("Username");
    dtm.addColumn("Status");

    getColumn("Username").setMinWidth(115);
    getColumn("Username").setMaxWidth(115);
    setRowHeight(20);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = source.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int column = source.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if(!source.isRowSelected(row))
                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
                buildPopup(row, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea how to change the size of the friends list? (Extends JTable)

**Note:** I have removed all "sizing" code from the friendslist, because I can't figure it out and wanted to give a "clean" solution, even without setting the bounds, it still pouplates at the same size. It's like trying to set the size manually is completely pointless.

Comment: `this.setLayout(null);` - first mistake; *friendslist.java (Extends JTable)* - second mistake.  There's very little reason to ever extend from a `JTable`...

Comment: The reason I'm extending from the JTable is to issue a select on right-click and create a popup menu, based on the rows values

Comment: Use an appropriate layout manager, add the `JTable` to a `JScrollPane`, put the `JScrollPane` onto your `SocialPanel`

Comment: What's the "Appropriate layout manager" for an 'Absolute' based layout? I want everything to be defined by pixel position, The only solution I came across was to use (null)

Comment: So, you can do this without extending from `JTable`, in fact, you could use `setComponentPopup`, but I'd just add a good old `MouseListener` to an instance of `JTable` and be done with it...

Comment: Alright, I'll do that then, I'm just following the tutorials I find online, but regardless of the extending the JTable, (Considering all of my tables in my application do what I want them to, besides for the sizing in this one) what about the layout?

Comment: So when the font metrics, DPI or other rendering pipeline changes occur your "pretty pixel perfect" layout blows up in your face? Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: `BorderLayout` would be start, `GridBagLayout` if you want something more complex, each comes down to needs...(also, I wrote a "table popup" support API for the current project I'm working on, allows more flexibility - you just need a `JTable` or something that extends from it). Have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: My problem with most of the layouts was not understanding how to position things exactly` where I wanted them, I spent almost two full man days trying to figure it out. I've seen so many games not use a layout, and instead use pixel perfection, which is what this is going to be. http://gyazo.com/dce859a6ad072d49bc40f2f3e452e08b

I'm just trying to fix up the social pane, the rest is nothing but sprites.

Comment: I see three basic `BorderLayout`s.  One for the center, left and bottom components, and another for the bottom table and search bar and one for the friends list, header/table/buttons...You don't always need a single layout, some times you need to create compound layouts, adding groups of components to a container and managing them separately...

Comment: Could you perhaps draw it out for me? I thank you for all the help, but when I attempted to use a borderlayout (which i did at first) i ended up with having stuff piling ontop of eachother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic example of how it might be possible to generate a similar layout using layout managers.  This example uses `BorderLayout`, `FlowLayout` and `GridBagLayout`

It also shows how to generate fixed width columns ;)

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel content = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(200, 200);
                    }
                };

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(content);
                frame.add(new FriendsPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
                frame.add(new MessagePane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FriendsPanel extends JPanel {

        public FriendsPanel() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel header = new JLabel("Social Pane");
            header.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(), new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8)));
            add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("");
            model.addColumn("");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er3107", "Offline"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er4360", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er187", "Offline"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er1040", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er427", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er4140", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er835", "Offline"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er2045", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er4525", "Online"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"er4864", "Offline"});

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(100, 200));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            Font font = table.getFont();
            FontMetrics fm = table.getFontMetrics(font);

            TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
            TableColumn column = cm.getColumn(0);
            int width = fm.stringWidth("M") * 8;
            column.setWidth(width);
            column.setMaxWidth(width);
            column.setMinWidth(width);
            column.setPreferredWidth(width);

            column = cm.getColumn(1);
            column.setPreferredWidth(width);

            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JButton btnF = new JButton("F");
            JButton btnI = new JButton("I");

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(), new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8)));
            buttons.add(btnF);
            buttons.add(btnI);
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public class MessagePane extends JPanel {

        public MessagePane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.addColumn("");
            model.addColumn("");
            model.addColumn("");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user4916", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user2916", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user4471", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user4161", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user2048", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"rank", "user3212", "..."});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"Admin", "Chris", "Testing..."});

            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

            Font font = table.getFont();
            FontMetrics fm = table.getFontMetrics(font);

            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200, fm.getHeight() * 9));

            TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
            TableColumn column = cm.getColumn(0);
            int width = fm.stringWidth("M") * 6;
            column.setWidth(width);
            column.setMaxWidth(width);
            column.setMinWidth(width);
            column.setPreferredWidth(width);

            width = fm.stringWidth("M") * 10;
            column = cm.getColumn(1);
            column.setWidth(width);
            column.setMaxWidth(width);
            column.setMinWidth(width);
            column.setPreferredWidth(width);

            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            buttons.add(new JTextField(5), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            buttons.add(new JButton("Send Chat"), gbc);
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll start moving everything over to this layout style, you have no idea how much it helped.

Comment: It's only a "possible" solution, but should give you some ideas of how to compound complex layouts together ;)